# into magento, I create new customer form from mobile and how to insert its value into customer table?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

I want to insert some information of customer into all customer tables from outside form but I am not able to insert it and I have also used following code :

```
$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
    ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
    ->setCountryId('US')
    //->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
    ->setPostcode('90210')
    ->setCity('Beverly Hills')
    ->setTelephone('123')
    ->setFax('123')
    ->setCompany('Company')
    ->setStreet('Street')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

try{
    $address->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

But I am getting some error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`customer_address_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE )' in C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array) in C:\wamp\www\magento\mmm\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234
```

Please help me and suggest me how to solve it so that I can insert some information of customer into database from outside form.
Thanks

Comment: please check customer id exit in system and also check  customer website

Comment: Your problem is, that you want to save a customer address without customer_id

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem and I used following code :

```
require PATH_TO_MAGENTO_FOLDER . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");  //If you want to insert only customer information into DB then use it.
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->setStore($store)
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->setGroupId(1) // if you want to change group then used GroupId 1 or 2 or 3 
        ->setPrefix('Sir')
        ->setFirstname('john')
        ->setMiddleName('2')
        ->setLastname('Doe')
        ->setSuffix('II')
        ->setEmail('abc@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('password')
        ->save();

$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address"); // If you also want to insert all address into DB then use it.
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
    ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
    ->setCountryId('IN')
    ->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
    ->setRegion('MP')
    ->setPostcode('31000')
    ->setCity('Osijek')
    ->setTelephone('0038511223344')
    ->setFax('0038511223355')
    ->setCompany('Inchoo')
    ->setStreet('Kersov')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('0')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
    ->save();
```